# Path terminal rollback to previous on VSCode after run code

Tags: python, visual-studio-code, anaconda

I'm using VSCode and Anaconda for virtual envs.

On a new folder (for a new project), I navigate to the folder of the project on VSCode terminal and activated the correct env for that project.

When I run any code from this folder, the terminal comeback to the folder it was previously, and I need to "cd" to the correct folder again.

I don't know if it is a VSCode configuration or an Anaconda.

What do I need to configure to keep the path after running the code?

Comment: Does the code change the current working directory in any way?

Comment: Nope @BrettCannon, it changes even if I just print a "Hello World".

Comment: Not sure what to tell you then since VS Code simply opens the terminal and activates the conda environment and that's it (basically you see everything that happens when you open the terminal). I would check to see what you have installed as there might be a PYTHONSTARTUP file or some module  that is  set to get imported at launch that's playing around with your environment.